# null pointer exception in DOM Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Im using the following code for xml node extraction , But im getting the nullpointer exception

```
<root>
<place >
    <city> aaaaaa </city> 
    <state / >
    <country> zzzzzzzz </country>
<place>

</root>
```

I have tried the following code

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath1.compile(temp).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);
TempFlat = nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

and i have googled and got this

```
 NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath1.compile(temp).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);
Node nValue = (Node) nodeList.getFirstChild();
```

where **temp** is my xpath . Which is readable from a file. example

```
/root/place/city
   /root/place/city
   /root/place/city
```

but for this im getting the following error

```
E:\Work\java\test.java:80: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFirstChild()
location: interface org.w3c.dom.NodeList
  Node nValue = (Node) nodeList.getFirstChild();
                                                                     ^
1 error
```

I found that , this is because `<state / >` is empty . How can i solve this . Can anyone help me

**NOTE :**  **I have found the reason for the 2nd error** i have posted , But i need to solve the **Null Pointer exception**

Comment: @AKS  Okay , Temp is my XPATH here , for example '/root/state'

Comment: What is your XML document's root element, and how is `<city>` related to it?  Edit your post to show the document structure all the way back to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeList` doesn't have any method `getFirstChild()`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

Once you have the `NodeList`

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath1.compile(temp).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

before getting any Node from the `nodeList`, check for it's length

```
if (nodeList.getLength() > 0)
    Node node = nodeList.items(0);
```

Similarly, once you have the `Node` and you want to get the first child here, you need to be sure that the node have some childs

```
if (node.hasChildNodes())
    String value = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

This way you can avoid `null` values.

Comment: Yes, I ahve seen this . I( just need a solution to solve this problem , My null pointer exception error

Answer (score 0):

Your compile error at the bottom of your post is due to the fact that there is no getFirstChild() method for org.w3c.dom.NodeList. See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html).

**But for your question**, you will need to check if the node exists before you call the getNodeValue() method. When you call getFirstChild() on the **state** node you will always get null because it has no children. So calling the getNodeValue() method on this null value will result in the NullPointerException you are seeing. To get around this you will check if the node exists first before you start looking for the value. Try something like the code below to fix your issue. I'm not sure what TempFlat is so I will assume it is a String variable.

```
String tempFlat = "DEFAULT VALUE";
if(noteList.item(0).hasChildNodes())
    tempFlat = nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,But could you mind anz how to solve the null pointer exception , Have a look on my updated post